# Change Tab Name in Notes Application

Tags: lotus-notes, domino-designer-eclipse

how can i change the name in the tab of an application? In my case the its the pernames.nsf

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [customize the Window Title Formula for a form](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/3655e73ada769faf85256c54004b6b3a?OpenDocument). You can't do this for views - which I believe is what you're showing above, but you can customize the title for a frameset and [set up your application to present views within the frameset](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Redbooks%3A%20Best%20Practices%20for%20Domino%208.0%20Web%20Application%20Development#action=openDocument&res_title=08072008120656PMKMKLVW.htm&content=pdcontent).

Answer (score 0):

The title of the personal address book is read from the owner that is written in a profile document. Just click on "More - Preferences" in the action bar of the contacts view and change the owner, then the title of the tab will change.